# Multi-div horizontal marquee via CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working on dressing up a scoreboard for a competition server that I run which is written in Angular.  On the scoreboard, if a user or team's name exceeds 12 characters, I apply a CSS class to the team or user score `div` to force it to scroll.

The issue is that, if the names are of varying lengths, I end up with the various elements scrolling differently, frequently with a partial scroll in some (possibly an "over scroll" if that makes sense, where it wraps around for another pass) that blinks out and then restarts, and some that do not always scroll all the way out of the `div`.

I'm looking for thoughts and recommendations.  CSS is absolutely my weak point.  Here is the current CSS that's being applied to all of the elements that are over 12 characters:

```
#marquee p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation-name: sidescroll;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function:  linear;
}

@keyframes sidescroll {
  0% { transform:translateX(125%); }
  100% { transform:translateX(-125%); }
}
```

and here's the Angular template:

```
    <div *ngIf="scorer.name.length > 12" class="element name" id="marquee"><p>{{scorer.name}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="scorer.name.length < 13" class="element name">{{scorer.name}}</div>
    <div class="element hints">{{scorer.hints}} hints</div>
    <div class="element lost">{{scorer.pointsLost}} lost</div>
    <div class="element svg" [innerHTML]="scorer.svg"></div>
    <div class="element score">{{scorer.score}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that, when using percentages, properties like `left` are relative to the container (closest positioned parent) size whereas `transform: translate` percentages are relative to the element size itself. You want your element to scroll from its left being on the right of the parent to its right being on the left of the parent, so you can use a combination of these properties.

```
#marquee {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#marquee::before {
    /* makes sure the height is correct as the position absolute p doesn't take any space */
    content: ' ';
    white-space: pre;
}

#marquee p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: sidescroll 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes sidescroll {
    0% {
        /* left side of the element */
        transform: translateX(0);
        /* on the right of the parent */
        left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        /* right side of the element */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* on the left of the parent */
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd7au9mn/)

Note: you forgot to close your P tag.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back.  Thanks!